# Filtering and sanitizing checkboxes input with PHP

Tags: php

I did quite a lot of reading and searching but there is something I cannot explain:

HTML code

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="onename[]" value="value 1">
<input type="checkbox" name="onename[]" value="value 2">
<input type="checkbox" name="onename[]" value="value 3">
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I ended up trying 2 different functions to get and filter these, the first one being the one I thought would work but does not, the second being the one that I didn't think would work but does ...

```
$first = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, 'onename', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

Returns nothing

```
$second = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'onename', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FORCE_ARRAY)
```

Return the proper array of submitted values (the one that were checked).

I think it's weird not using filter_input_array which is meant for arrays, does anybody know why it's not working ? (My syntax is applying the same filter for all values which is what I want).

Comment: Remember, the browser does not send checkboxes to the back end if they are not checked. You need to know what should be coming, check if it exists, and if it does not then it was not checked

Comment: @RiggsFolly : sorry but I am way beyond that question of knowing if my checkboxes are checked or unchecked, I'm talking about checked ckeckboxes and the fact that only the second function works properly while I thought only the first would work ... INPUT_POST means I know how and where from is the data coming ...

Answer (score 0):

There is the `FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY` flag that can be set which should help filter the `POST`ed values as expected

```
<?php

    $field='onename';
    
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST[ $field ] ) ){
        ob_clean();
        
        $args=array(
            'onename'   =>  array(
                'filter'    =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT,
                'flags'     =>  FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY*
            )
        );
        $_POST=filter_input_array( INPUT_POST, $args );
        
        printf('<pre>%s</pre>', print_r( $_POST, true ) );
        
        exit();
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="checkbox" name="onename[]" value="value 1" />
            <input type="checkbox" name="onename[]" value="value 2" />
            <input type="checkbox" name="onename[]" value="value 3" />
            <input type="submit" />
        </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Which outputs something like the following depending upon which checkboxes were checked:

```
Array
(
    [onename] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
        )

)
```

Comment: I don't kow why but this does not work here while my second function using "filter_input" does work perfectly. Weird. Thanks.

Comment: please explain `"this does not work here"` as it seems to work fine

Comment: Of course i am not using your code exactly as is, I am adapting it at my specific script, but I think I am being very close and the array returned is empty (print_r displays nothing). If I use $_POST['onename'] or filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'onename', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FORCE_ARRAY) or filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'onename', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY) I get an array with the values checked. I didn't use "ob_clean()", not sure why you do this ...

Comment: The `ob_clean()` should not have been there - it is useful when doing an ajax request to the same page (and I lifted that portion from such a page)